# ecryptfs-migrate-home on btrfs file system (Ubuntu)

Tags: encryption, btrfs

I plan to encrypt home directory with `ecryptfs-migrate-home`. I have btrfs system and I use timeshift backup to create snapshots.

I would like to know how btrfs snapshots work on encrypted home directory. Snapshots are located outside of the home directory, on the same btrfs partition in directory `/run/timeshift/backup/@home` directory. Are the snapshots still encrypted? Will the contents of the snapshot show normal filenames or encrypted?

Answer (score 1):

I did some experiments so I have an answer. After home directory encryption is run, a new directory within `/home` is created and it contains ensrypted files of a user. That directory is then backed up as snapshot. You can therefore restore encrypted user directory from snapshot, but you cannot browse files in snapshot, because they are encrypted.

Comment: That's interesting. How is it going so far, after couple years? Is it safe to use file level encryption with Btrfs?